# Python import X or from X import Y? (performance)

Tags: python, performance

If there is a library from which I'm going to use at least two methods, is there any difference in performance or memory usage between the following?

```
from X import method1, method2
```

and

```
import X
```

Answer (score 54):

There is a difference, because in the `import x` version there are two name lookups: one for the module name, and the second for the function name; on the other hand, using `from x import y`, you have only one lookup.

You can see this quite well, using the dis module:

```
import random
def f_1():
    random.seed()

dis.dis(f_1)
     0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (random)
     3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (seed)
     6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
     9 POP_TOP
    10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
    13 RETURN_VALUE

from random import seed

def f_2():
    seed()

dis.dis(f_2)
     0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (seed)
     3 CALL_FUNCTION            0
     6 POP_TOP
     7 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
    10 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, using the form `from x import y` is a bit faster.

On the other hand, `import x` is less expensive than `from x import y`, because there's a name lookup less; let's look at the disassembled code:

```
def f_3():
    import random

dis.dis(f_3)
     0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
     3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
     6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (random)
     9 STORE_FAST               0 (random)
    12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
    15 RETURN_VALUE

def f_4():
    from random import seed

dis.dis(f_4)
     0 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
     3 LOAD_CONST               2 (('seed',))
     6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (random)
     9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (seed)
    12 STORE_FAST               0 (seed)
    15 POP_TOP
    16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
    19 RETURN_VALUE
```

I do not know the reason, but it seems the form `from x import y` looks like a function call, and therefore is even more expensive than anticipated; for this reason, if the imported function is used only once, it means it would be faster to use `import x`, while if it is being used more than once, it becomes then faster to use `from x import y`.

That said, as usual, I would suggest you **not** following this knowledge for your decision on how to import modules and functions, because this is just some premature optimization.
Personally, I think in a lot of cases, explicit namespaces are much more readable, and I would suggest you doing the same: use your own sense of esthetic :-)

Comment: It's one opcode on the virtual machine. Let that take 10 cycles and that is **5 nanoseconds** on a 2 Ghz machine. Just reading this sentence takes more time than the program could save in your lifetime.

Comment: @THC4k: I don't think any of us are disagreeing with you, I certainly agree with the "use whatever makes sense". @Roberto: I did some more timeit tests with multiple calls... the `from ...` statement starts to get slightly faster after ~8 function calls.  It's interesting, but not important... we're dealing with microseconds of difference here.

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit.  Namespaces are one honking great idea—let's do more of those!   by https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python

Comment: @JochenRitzel I know I'm late, but I feel obligated to comment: that estimate is not even remotely correct. 1) Not all instructions take a single cycle. Memory accesses in particular, which these will involve, take quite a few. 2) *bytecode* ops are not the same as assembly ops. "Bytecode" is just an intermediate language that the python is compiled to before being passed to an *interpreter*. Every one of those bytecode lines results in dozens of function calls and thousands of instructions, most of which access main memory. It does *not* take 5ns. More like *180,000*.

Answer (score 11):

There is no memory or speed difference (the whole module has to be evaluated either way, because the last line could be `Y = something_else`). Unless your computer is from the 1980s it doesn't matter anyways.

Comment: In my project, doing 40 imports from PyQt5 causes 500 ms lag during start up, which I find unacceptable. That's on SSD and i7-4790K. Because of this I'm probably going to shift to C++, so yes, it matters... perhaps not in exactly OPs question's context, but it shows that imports can cause performance problems indeed.

Comment: @rr- Shed Skin, Cython, or Nuitka can compile Python as C.

Answer (score 10):

It can matter if you are calling a function a lot of times in a loop (millions or more).  Doing the double dictionary lookup will eventually accumulate.  The example below shows a 20% increase.

Times quoted are for Python 3.4 on a Win7 64 bit machine.  (Change the range command to xrange for Python 2.7).

This example is highly based on the book [High Performance Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449361595), although their third example of local function lookups being better no longer seemed to hold for me.

```
import math
from math import sin

def tight_loop_slow(iterations):
    """
    >>> %timeit tight_loop_slow(10000000)
    1 loops, best of 3: 3.2 s per loop
    """
    result = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        # this call to sin requires two dictionary lookups
        result += math.sin(i)

def tight_loop_fast(iterations):
    """
    >>> %timeit tight_loop_fast(10000000)
    1 loops, best of 3: 2.56 s per loop
    """
    result = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        # this call to sin only requires only one lookup
        result += sin(i)
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe there's any real difference, and generally worrying about that little amount of memory isn't typically worth it. If you're going to be pressing memory considerations, it will far more likely be in your code.