# which way of importing is better in python and some clarifications on the class objects

Tags: python, class, object, import

I have a python file named Point2.py, which has the following code

```
class Point():   
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return "%d,%d" %(self.x,self.y)
```

Now in the interpreter, I did this:

```
>>> import Point2
>>> p1 = Point()
```

But I received an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The Point2.py file has Point class in it. Why I am not able to assign it to p1. When I tried:

```
>>> from Point import *

>>> p1 = Point()
```

It works

I renamed the file to Point.py and then I did

```
>>> import Point
>>> p1 = Point
```

and this works, but assigning values are not easy.

However,

```
>>> from Point import *
>>> p1 = Point(3,4)
```

works.

My question is why it behaves differently when I import Point and when I did from Point import *. Which way of importing is a good style?

And is there any relevance for class and the filename?

Comment: Use `from Point2 import Point` and it won't import *everything* like `*` does. See more on Haidro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer why:

```
>>> import Point2
>>> p1 = Point()
```

doesn't work, is because you did not directly import the class Point(). To access the `Point()` class, you'll want to do:

```
>>> import Point2
>>> p1 = Point2.Point()
```

Or

```
>>> from Point2 import Point
>>> p1 = Point()
```

Doing `from x import *` imports *everything* from the module. So if there was a function `foo()` in a module `bar`, doing `from bar import foo` would import the function so you could do `foo()` and not have to do `bar.foo()`. This is why when you did `from Point import *`, it worked as you didn't need to do `Point.Point()`.

---

Which way is better to import? Well, doing `from x import *` isn't recommended unless you're going to use everything in `x`. It can also get mixed up with functions in your own script.

With `from x import y` or `import x`, take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591962/python-import-x-or-from-x-import-y-performance).

Comment: Thanks, I got it clear now. One other offshoot question I have is

Comment: Thanks, I got it clear now. One other offshoot question I have is what difference I have if I define a method in my Point class as def add(self,other) and def __add__(self,other). i.e, what is the differnce here, def __add__(self,other):
       return "%d,%d" %(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y)

   def addtwo(self,other):
       return "%d,%d" %(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y)                                            and how to use them would be very helpful

Comment: I don't believe there is a difference (I myself aren't very experienced with classes) but to use them, you would do `a = Point()` `a.__add__(x)` where x is/are your parameter/s.

Comment: In your case you should be returning numbers, instead of strings for your add. `def __add__(self,other): return (self.x+other+x, self.y+other.y)` Actually maybe you should be returning a new Point() with the new values. That i'm not sure.