# Why does "from [Module] import [Something]" takes more time than "import [Module"

Tags: python, timeit

I used `python -mtimeit` to test and found out it takes more time to `from Module import Sth` comparing to `import Module`

E.g.

```
$ python -mtimeit "import math; math.sqrt(4)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.618 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit "from math import sqrt; sqrt(4)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 usec per loop
```

same for other case. Could someone please explain the rationale behind? Thank you!

Comment: Possibly take a look at this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3592137/1679863

Comment: I suggest not worrying about why this happens (past intellectual curiosity) and use whatever makes your code most readable.

Comment: @RohitJain: I like the hypothesis. However, `python -mtimeit "from math import pow, sqrt, sin, fabs, ceil, floor, fmod"` only takes a fraction more than `python -mtimeit "from math import pow"`, which doesn't support the theory.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here. The first step is to figure out which part is faster: the import statement, or the call.

So, let's do that:

```
$ python -mtimeit 'import math'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.555 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit 'from math import sqrt'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'from math import sqrt' 'sqrt(10)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0879 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s 'import math' 'math.sqrt(10)'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.122 usec per loop
```

(That's with Apple CPython 2.7.2 64-bit on OS X 10.6.4 on my laptop. But python.org 3.4 dev on the same laptop and 3.3.1 on a linux box give roughly similar results. With PyPy, the smarter caching makes it impossible to test, since everything finishes in 1ns… Anyway, I think these results are probably about as portable as microbenchmarks ever can be.)

So it turns out that the `import` statement is more than twice as fast; after that, calling the function is a little slower, but not nearly enough to make up for the cheaper `import`. (Keep in mind that your test was doing an `import` for each call. In real-life code, of course, you tend to call things a lot more than once per `import`. So, we're really looking at an edge case that will rarely affect real code. But as long as you keep that in mind, we proceed.)

---

Conceptually, you can understand why the `from … import` statement takes longer: it has more work to do. The first version has to find the module, compile it if necessary, and execute it. The second version has to do all of that, and then *also* extract `sqrt` and insert it into your current module's globals. So, it has to be at least a little slower.

If you look at the bytecode (e.g., by using the [`dis`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) module and calling `dis.dis('import math')`), this is exactly the difference. Compare:

```
  0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0) 
  3 LOAD_CONST               1 (None) 
  6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (math) 
  9 STORE_NAME               0 (math) 
 12 LOAD_CONST               1 (None) 
 15 RETURN_VALUE
```

… to:

```
  0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0) 
  3 LOAD_CONST               1 (('sqrt',)) 
  6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (math) 
  9 IMPORT_FROM              1 (sqrt) 
 12 STORE_NAME               1 (sqrt) 
 15 POP_TOP              
 16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None) 
 19 RETURN_VALUE
```

The extra stack manipulation (the `LOAD_CONST` and `POP_TOP`) probably doesn't make much difference, and using a different argument to `STORE_NAME` is unlikely to matter at all… but the `IMPORT_FROM` is a significant extra step.

---

Surprisingly, a quick&dirty attempt to profile the `IMPORT_FROM` code shows that the majority of the cost is actually looking up the appropriate globals to import into. I'm not sure why, but… that implies that importing a whole slew of names should be not much slower than importing just one. And, as you pointed out in a comment, that's exactly what you see. (But don't read too much into that. There are many reasons that `IMPORT_FROM` might have a large constant factor and only a small linear one, and we're not exactly throwing a huge number of names at it.)

---

One last thing: If this ever really does matter in real code, and you want to get the best of both worlds, `import math; sqrt = math.sqrt` is faster than `from math import sqrt`, but gives you the same small speedup to lookup/call time. (But again, I can't imagine any real code where this would matter. The only time you'll ever care how long `sqrt` takes is when you're calling it a billion times, at which point you won't care how long the import takes. Plus, if you really do need to optimize that, create a local scope and bind `sqrt` there to avoid the global lookup entirely.)

Comment: Whoever downvoted, care to explain why?

Comment: loool, not me, not me

Comment: For people like me, new to python bytecode, how did you get the instruction list?

Comment: @SeanMcLaughlin: See the `dis` module. I'll update the answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but some information.  It needed formatting so I didn't include it as a comment.  Here is the bytecode for 'from math import sqrt':

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> import dis
>>> def f(n): return sqrt(n)
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sqrt)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

And for 'import math'

```
>>> import math
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(math.sqrt)
>>> def f(n): return math.sqrt(n)
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (math)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (sqrt)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (n)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Interestingly, the faster method has one more instruction.

Comment: Is the method actually faster? I'm pretty sure that the _import statement_ is actually what's taking twice as long, not the function call.

Comment: In fact, from a quick test, the actually function is actually _slower_ using `math.sqrt`, 0.122us vs. 0.0879us. But the `import` statement is much faster using `import math`, 0.555us vs. 1.222us. So, this information is irrelevant.

Comment: How did you separate the run time from the load time?

Comment: I explained that in my answer. To get just the import times, I called `timeit` with just the import statements. To get just the function call times, I passed the import statements as setup code instead of as part of the main code (`-s` from the command-line interface).