# Unable to import another python module same level

Tags: python, django, flash-message

I have a file called

```
server.py
```

another called `constants.py`

```
constants.py
```

is on the same level as `server.py`

Here is what I am doing:

**server.py**

```
import constants
def hello_world():
   print(BUCKET_NAME)
```

**constants.py**

`BUCKET_NAME = 'uw-note-share'`

I am getting the error:

`NameError: global name 'BUCKET_NAME' is not defined`

Even though I am properly importing. What is the issue?

Comment: `constants.BUCKET_NAME`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> Enter the Python interpreter and import this module with the following command:
>   `import fibo`
>   This does not enter the names of the functions defined in `fibo` directly in the current symbol table; it only enters the module name `fibo` there.
>
> Each module has its own private symbol table, which is used as the global symbol table by all functions defined in the module. Thus, the author of a module can use global variables in the module without worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global variables. On the other hand, if you know what you are doing you can touch a module’s global variables with the same notation used to refer to its functions, `modname.itemname`.

This may seem very complicated, but what it says is basically, when you import a module, all of its contents remain in a separate [namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) in order to prevent collisions (i.e. two variables in two modules with the exact same name).

Lets take your example. For your code to work you have two options.

**Option A**

Explicitly tell python that the variable you're looking for is defined in the `constants` module.

```
import constants
def hello_world():
   print(constants.BUCKET_NAME)
```

**Option B**

Again, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules):

> There is a variant of the import statement that imports names from a module directly into the importing module’s symbol table.

This variant is the following:

```
from module import x
```

What this does is it imports everything one by one from the `constants` module. From then on, python treats that data as if it was defined in your current module.

Using this approach, you can do the following:

```
from constants import *
def hello_world():
   print(BUCKET_NAME)
```

The `*` here tells python to import *everything* from that module. This is convenient in a lot of cases, however be advised, this may cause performance issues when dealing with large modules. Also, keep in mind:

> This does not introduce the module name from which the imports are taken in the local symbol table

What this means is that if you opt to only import `BUCKET_NAME` from constants (`from constants import BUCKET_NAME` instead of `import *`), `constants` won't be defined. You will not be able to access other variables defined in that module without *also* writing `import constants`.

For a more detailed explanation regarding the performance of the latter approach, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3592137/7662085) excellent post by [Roberto Liffredo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43927/roberto-liffredo), as well as [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187471) by resident python master [Martijn Pieters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/55400/martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 2):

Try ,

```
from constants import BUCKET_NAME
print(BUCKET_NAME)
```

Or you could,

```
import constants
print(constants.BUCKET_NAME)
```

When we import a module, we are making it available to us in our current program as a separate namespace. This means that we will have to refer to the function in dot notation, as in [module].[function].

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import whole file itself. You can get it to work in two ways,

```
import constants
def hello_world():
   print(constants.BUCKET_NAME)
```

OR

```
from constants import BUCKET_NAME
def hello_world():
   print(BUCKET_NAME)
```

I hope this helps you.